# How do you display related records in QGIS?

Tags: postgis, qgis, postgresql

Coming from an esri background I have always used relationship classes in a gdb to display records related to a feature. Eg. Relate 1 survey point to many documents, photos etc.

Does any one know how to do something similar in QGIS?

Ando

P.S I'm using PostGreSQL 8.4.1 and PostGIS 1.4 and my clients are QGIS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

-There is a plugin named "eVis Event Browser" it will display images or any document based on external applications.

-You can create relational layers (generated from SQL queries) with the plugin "RT SQL Layer".

[image: eVis]

Comment: I have heard of eVis but its not quite what i'm looking for, I don't like how users have to use a different identify tool when using it. "RT SQL Layer" is something I will have a look at.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create custom actions that reference a particular field.  Example for opening a website (stored in a field named "yourfieldname") in firefox you would use the sytax below.  The downside to this method is you would have to create an action for every field that has hotlink data in it, plus an action that would open the correct type of document.  You can get to the action by right-clicking on the field in the standard Identify window.

"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" %yourfieldname

(yourfieldname is **CASE SENSITIVE**)

[image]

Comment: Hi Ryan, thanks for the response. I am interested in how to relate to multiple records. The above suggestion of RT SQL Layer is handy but makes a new layer, and I don't want that. What I originally thought it may be possible to use actions to execute a query of my attachments table and return the records in a table. I have posted on the QGIS forum, unfortunately no responses there yet http://forum.qgis.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=7984

Comment: Yeah, its not quite as seamless as ArcGIS.  Definitely post a response if you get a better answer.