# QGIS Create Map for Each Attribute using Python

Tags: qgis, python, choropleth

I'm new to GIS and QGIS. I've looked through several of the related questions including [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/142731/qgis-2-8-generate-a-series-of-map-for-each-field-of-the-attribute-table) and [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/85854/batch-map-creation-iterated-over-attributes-of-a-layer-in-qgis), but can't figure out a simple way to automate creating choropleths for each attribute in a shapefile using QGIS but strictly from Python. I figured this was a relatively common use case.

I gave up after about four or so hours of trying to figure it out and wrote this simple code that produces the ~300 pngs that I need:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sp = gpd.read_file(<shapefile filename goes here>)
column_list = sp.columns.values
for i in column_list: 
    sp.plot(column = i, cmap='Blues', alpha=1, legend=True, linewidth=0)
    plt.savefig(i +'.png', dpi=600,bbox_inches='tight')
```

Again this works fine for what I needed, but is there an implementation in QGIS? I'd like to get better with this software/package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one method of how to do this:

1. Define a list variable containing the field names that you want to create a choropleth on
2. Loop over step 1 list and create an in-memory layer with the field name and populate it (attributes and features) from source layer and add it to canvas (see code example: [Duplicating layer in memory using pyqgis?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/205947/duplicating-layer-in-memory-using-pyqgis))
3. Create the categorized renderer for the in-memory layer (see code example: [Apply symbol to each feature (Categorized symbol)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/175068/apply-symbol-to-each-feature-categorized-symbol))
4. Continue looping steps 2-3