# One-to-many joins in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins, one-to-many

I am looking for a possibility to make a one-to-many table-join in QGIS.

I have a shapefile with postal codes and would like to join them with survey results (more than one). In other words, there is a specific postal code (shapefile) on one side and there are many survey participants on the other side.

```
postal **code1** ----- survey participant **1**
postal **code1** ----- survey participant **2**
postal **code1** ----- survey participant **3**
postal **code2** ----- survey participant **1**
postal **code2** ----- survey participant **2**
and so on ...
```

If I do a normal join (right click on `Layer --> Properties --> Join`) , I just get the first entry of the table with the postal codes.

I found out a way to do it ArcGIS with the tool `"Make Query Table"`, but I´m looking for a possibility to do it in QGIS.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 6):

Depending on what exactly you want to do, you can use the relations functionality in QGIS.

See https://web.archive.org/web/20160313201132/http://blog.vitu.ch/10112013-1201/qgis-relations

This allows you show a table of related participants on the feature form of a zip code.

The QGIS 3.10 documentation of this feature is at https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html?#creating-one-or-many-to-many-relations

Comment: That a neat article thanks for sharing, can you expand this answer to include the parts that are relevant to this question? Sometimes links get broken and I think GIS.se tries to discourage link only answers.

Comment: The link to the blog post above is broken. Is there somewhere else that holds that post?

Answer (score 0):

You may use a processing scripts.

And here the one for an attributes cross-joining:
https://github.com/kiselev-dv/QGIS-Processing/blob/master/scripts/spatial_cross_join_attributes.py

You may copy that script into `{QGIS_HOME_DIR}/processing/scripts` and use it via processing menu.

You have zip codes as an shape file, but I don't get in what form do you have survey data?

If they are points, import them as a new layer, and run `spatial_cross_join_attributes` script. It will asks you for two layers and name of results table. And in result table you'll get one row for each pair of zip and enclosed point.

```
zip1 point1
zip1 point2
zip2 point3
```

Comment: The survey data is a simple table (.csv) without any geometrys.

Comment: I got a one zip code and many survey participants.