# Join multiple rows to a single feature in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, infowindow

I have this kind of csv attribute table:

```
          ID INVENT_KPV KASVUKOHA_KOOD RINDE_KOOD PUULIIGI_KOOD VANUS
297945203711 2009.08.31             MO          1            KS    60
297945203711 2009.08.31             MO          2            KU    50
297945303711 2009.08.31             SS          1            MA    60
297945303711 2009.08.31             SS          1            KS    60
297945403711 2009.08.31             JO          1            HB    NA
```

As you can see, there are 3 different ID codes. I have also a map in QGIS and I want to join this attribute table and the map together but the problem is that when I use the button **"info"** in QGIS and click on the map then it shows me only information about **one row** not all of them (which have the same IDs).

For example, if I click somewhere in the map where's a patch with ID 297945303711 then it only shows me: 2009.08.31, SS, 1, **MA**, 60 **and not** 2009.08.31, SS, 1, **KS**, 60.

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @user87586! Perhaps this post might help: [One-to-many join in QGIS](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/155871/one-to-many-join-in-qgis)

Answer (score 1):

**QGIS3**

At the time of question, it required either `relation` or `virtual layer` approach.

Now there is a new function **Join attributes by field value** which can handle `one-to-many` relationship.

[image]

You have `ID` codes in both layers, so just assign it to both `Table field` and `Table field 2`.

[image]

This tool duplicates the feature to accommodate multiple input records.

Also note the last record in the above example `ID= 297945403711` does not have any corresponding data in your CSV, so it ends up with blank cells other than the data from original feature.