# Link multiple value from table to point shapefile

Tags: qgis, shapefile, attribute-joins, table

In QGis 2.18 is there a way to link (like join) a table with **multiple value** for each ID CODE with a Point shapefile **with only 1 point for each ID CODE**?? (picture in annex)

It would be fine also a temporary link in my machine memory to keep light the shapefile!

[image: example]

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [One-to-many join in QGIS](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/155871/one-to-many-join-in-qgis)

Comment: Unfortunately the blog link on the post about QGis relations is broken.

Comment: Then maybe this might help?
http://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#creating-one-to-many-relations

Comment: Ok "Relations" works!! The multiple value table now compare in annex to Point Shapefile Attribute table. But is there a way, after the selection from point shapefile to select (and export) also the connected multipla value from table 2?