# QGIS - merging two tables

Tags: qgis-2.18

I need help with merging two different tables in QGIS. First table is normal atribute table for spatial layer. Second table is text .dbf file without geometry. I cant use "join" feature, because in text file I have more (two or three) lines to one line in spatial layer. In ArcView 3 is "Link" feature and in ArcGis 3.2 is "Relate" feature. In QGIS I am helpless.

[image]

Comment: This may help: [Joining multiple records to single feature using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10788/joining-multiple-records-to-single-feature-using-qgis) I like the Virtual Layer way posted by underdark.

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer, but I would like to recommend **Virtual Layer** [suggested by underdark](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10788/joining-multiple-records-to-single-feature-using-qgis).

For your case:

(1) Go to `Layer | Add Layer | Add/Edit Virtual Layer` and <kbd>import</kbd> both layers.

[image]

(2) Query is

```
SELECT aaa.*, bbb.*
FROM aaa CROSS JOIN bbb
ON aaa.SEGMENT_ID = bbb.SEGMENT_ID
```

Please replace `aaa` and `bbb` with real layer name, as appear in the `Local name`.

If you open the attribute table of the newly created layer, called `virtual layer`, it will be like below image.

[image]

Sorry for my posting multiple answers... but again, I really recommend this approach.

Answer (score 0):

The *Link* and *Relate* function you are looking for  is called **Relation** in QGIS. It is suggested by antrin in this [Q&A](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10788/joining-multiple-records-to-single-feature-using-qgis), which finally links it up to Matthias Kuhn's [blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20160313201132/http://blog.vitu.ch/10112013-1201/qgis-relations) site.

To keep the answer stay within this GIS-SE, let me try to summarize the steps to be taken. (If you have already read these links, there is nothing new in this answer).

---

(1) Assume your data has `aaa` point layer and `bbb` dbf layer, with `SEGMENT_ID` fields as KEY identifier.

[image]

(2) Go to menu `Project | Project Properties` and open `Relations` tab.

[image]

(3) Click on <kbd>[ + ] Add Relation</kbd> button. In the 1:N (parent to child) relationship, your point layer (single record) is the parent and dbf (many records) is the child. [OK] to close.

[image]

(4) Reopening the `aaa` attribute table may not look different. Then click on the `Switch to form view` (at the lower right corner).

[image]

(5) `Form view` shows the relationship between `aaa` and `bbb`.

[image]